# Proposal: WWDC Keynote Live Chat Event

Tags: discussion

As most of us know, each year Apple hosts its Worldwide Developers Conference (WWDC). Typically, Apple launches the WWDC with a keynote address during which it introduces upcoming software and hardware.

This year the conference will be held in San Jose, California, from Monday 5 June until Friday 9 June.

Below is part of the invite Apple issued for the event:

[image]

My proposal is that we hold a live chat event right here using [Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat). The way I see this working is that we invite users to join us in chat as the WWDC announcements unfold.

**Expected announcements**

- iOS 11
- macOS 10.13
- tvOS 11
- watchOS 4.

**Rumoured announcements**

- Revised MacBook, MacBook Pro and MacBook Air models
- A totally new Siri Smart Speaker (similar to Amazon Echo or Google Home)
- A new 10.5" iPad Pro.

**Surprise announcements**

- Let's have a live chat event and find out together! :)

**Time of Keynote address**

The Keynote address is scheduled for 10am on Monday 5 June (Pacific Time). This equates to:

- **Adelaide** - 2.30am, Tuesday 6 June
- **Amsterdam** - 7.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **Auckland** - 5.00am, Tuesday 6 June
- **Beijing** - 1.00am, Tuesday 6 June
- **Berlin** - 7.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **Hong Kong** - 1.00am, Tuesday 6 June
- **Jerusalem** - 8.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **London** - 6.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **Moscow** - 8.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **New Delhi** - 10.30pm, Monday 5 June
- **New York** - 1.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **Paris** - 7.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **Perth** - 1.00am, Tuesday 6 June
- **Rio de Janeiro** - 2.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **Rome** - 7.00pm, Monday 5 June
- **Singapore** - 1.00am, Tuesday 6 June
- **Sydney** - 3.00am, Tuesday 6 June
- **Tokyo** - 2.00am, Tuesday 6 June

**You can also check your local timezone** [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=Ask%20Different%20WWDC%20Live%20Chat%20Event&iso=20170605T10&p1=283).

So, for some of us (me included) it'll be a very late night or a very early morning!

To vote for or against this proposal, **please upvote the appropriate answer below** (i.e. you only need to upvote one answer - upvote 'yes' if we should do this, upvote 'no' if we should not).

Also, please feel free to offer comments in support of your vote.

Comment: 7pm, I like the timing :-)

Comment: Haha, a __lot__ better than the 3am I have to be up for! :(

Comment: 6pm, easy for me... & for a change, I won't be abroad on holiday trying to scrape a watchable version of it over some beach-bar 26kbps WiFi ;)

Comment: 10:30 for me...all of you lucky chumps ;(. Also, this should totally happen!

Comment: 1:00pm for me! Will have to leave wifi before its over... :( I'll be home just in time for recap.

Answer (score 16):

### Yes -- we should hold a WWDC live event chat via Ask Different Chat

Comment: Not everything needs a poll — a simple +/- vote on the question should be sufficient! :)

Comment: Haha, I _did_ think that originally, but then I thought you could have 20 people upvote and 20 people downvote and that'd look like it was a non-event, even though you'd have 20 people willing to join in. But maybe I was over-thinking it! :)

Answer (score -6):

### No -- we should not hold a WWDC live event chat via Ask Different Chat

Comment: -1 this doesn't answer the question :D

Comment: Does a down vote on a No mean a Yes?

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know. LOL Next time I'll approach this a little differently! :)